# OneToOne User Jhipster relationship

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I have created a UserExtra entity with OneToOne relationship to User entity like this

**User.java**

```
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

...

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "user")
    private UserExtra userExtra;
```

**UserExtra.java**

```
public class UserExtra extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;
    ...

}
```

But, when I search a user on terminal appears this error:

```
SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity]
Reported exception:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:449)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at co.interedes.domain.UserExtra.toString(UserExtra.java:91)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
```

Comment: How did you implement toString() in UserExtra? This is the cause of the infinite recursion as shown in stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, probably, because you have a circular reference in your `toString()` methods. This means `User` prints `UserExtra`, and `UserExtra` prints `User` entering a never ending loop.

One way to fix this is to simply remove the `User` from the `toString()` method inside `UserExtra` or have it print only the `User` ID instead of the whole object.